# iPhone 4s iOS 9.0.1 Won't update

Tags: ios, itunes, software-update, software

Im having problems updating iOS 9.0.1
I've deleted most apps so memory is fine, yet the phone appears to be frozen.

I can't restart or reset it. I've updated only 1 other bit - can't remember how I did it.

I've no laptop or PC & the wifi isn't great.
Any suggestions very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

- You can try pressing the home and sleep button down at the same time until you see the apple logo.
- You can wait until the battery is empty.
- You can ask a friend or family member for a PC / Laptop (should also work on an public computer) and download and restore it with iTunes.

I hoped I helped you out!

*Mark